# Merge documents from 2 collections in MongoDB & preserve property of a field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two collections, 1. temporaryCollection, 2. permanentCollection, I would like to take data from temporaryCollection and update in permanentCollection. To see the expected result see updatedPermanentCollection below.

Fields that are taken from Temporary collection and updated in Permanent collection are:

1. emailAddresses
2. phoneNumbers
3. ContactName
4. ContactNumber

For your info, the fields that are changed in Temporary collection

1. contacts[0]['emailAddresses']
2. contacts[0]['ContactName']
3. contacts[0]["phoneNumbers"]
4. contacts[0]["ContactNumber"]

Field that are that should not be changed after updation in UpdatedPermanentCollection is

```
contacts._id
```

Note: `contacts` is an Array of objects, for simplicity I have shown just one object.

I am currently using the below query which updates the permanentCollection but also overrides the `contacts._id` field. I don't want the `contacts._id` field to be overridden.

**Here is my MongoDB Query**

```
db.temporaryCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userID: ObjectId("61d1efea2c0fab00340f47c8"),
    },
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "permanentCollection",
      on: "userID",
      whenMatched: "merge",
      whenNotMatched: "insert",
    },
  },
]);
```

**1. temporaryCollection**

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "61d1f04266289f003452d705" },
  "userID": { "$oid": "61d1efea2c0fab00340f47c8" },
  "contacts": [
    {
      "emailAddresses": [
        { "id": "6884", "label": "email1", "email": "addedemail@gmail.com" }
      ],
      "phoneNumbers": [
        {
          "label": "other",
          "id": "4594",
          "number": "+918984292930"
        },
        {
          "label": "other",
          "id": "4595",
          "number": "+911234567890"
        }
      ],
      "_id": { "$oid": "61d1f04266289f003452d744" },
      "ContactName": "Sample User 1 Name Changed",
      "ContactNumber": "+918984292930",
      "recordID": "833"
    }
  ],
  "userNumber": "+911234567890",
  "__v": 7
}
```

**2. permanentCollection**

```
    {
  "_id": { "$oid": "61d1f04266289f003452d701" },
  "userID": { "$oid": "61d1efea2c0fab00340f47c8" },
  "contacts": [
    {
      "emailAddresses": [],
      "phoneNumbers": [
        {
          "label": "other",
          "id": "4594",
          "number": "+918984292929"
        },
        {
          "label": "other",
          "id": "4595",
          "number": "+911234567890"
        }
      ],
      "_id": { "$oid": "61d1f04266289f003452d722" },
      "ContactName": "Sample User 1",
      "ContactNumber": "+918984292929",
      "recordID": "833"
    }
  ],
  "userNumber": "+911234567890",
  "__v": 7
}
```

**3. updatedPermanentCollection (Expected result)**

```
    {
  "_id": { "$oid": "61d1f04266289f003452d701" },
  "userID": { "$oid": "61d1efea2c0fab00340f47c8" },
  "contacts": [
    {
      "emailAddresses": [
        { "id": "6884", "label": "email1", "email": "addedemail@gmail.com" }
      ],
      "phoneNumbers": [
        {
          "label": "other",
          "id": "4594",
          "number": "+918984292930"
        },
        {
          "label": "other",
          "id": "4595",
          "number": "+911234567890"
        }
      ],
      "_id": { "$oid": "61d1f04266289f003452d722" },
      "ContactName": "Sample User 1 Name Changed",
      "ContactNumber": "+918984292930",
      "recordID": "833"
    }
  ],
  "userNumber": "+911234567890",
  "__v": 7
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this aggregation query.

```
db.temporarCollection.aggreagate(
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "permanantCollection", 
      "let": {
        "user_id": "$userID"
      }, 
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$$user_id", "$userID"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ], 
      "as": "pcontacts"
    }
  }, {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$pcontacts", 
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  }, {
    "$project": {
      "contacts": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$contacts", 
          "as": "contact", 
          "in": {
            "tcontact": "$$contact", 
            "pcontact": {
              "$first": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$pcontacts.contacts", 
                  "as": "pcontact", 
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$pcontact.recordID", "$$contact.recordID"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }, 
      "userNumber": 1, 
      "userID": 1, 
      "_id": 0
    }
  }, {
    "$project": {
      "contacts": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$contacts", 
          "as": "contact", 
          "in": {
            "emailAddresses": "$$contact.tcontact.emailAddresses", 
            "phoneNumbers": "$$contact.tcontact.phoneNumbers", 
            "ContactName": "$$contact.tcontact.ContactName", 
            "ContactNumber": "$$contact.tcontact.ContactNumber", 
            "recordID": {
              "$let": {
                "vars": {}, 
                "in": {
                  "$cond": {
                    "if": "$$contact.pcontact.recordID", 
                    "then": "$$contact.pcontact.recordID", 
                    "else": "$$contact.tcontact.recordID"
                  }
                }
              }
            }, 
            "_id": {
              "$let": {
                "vars": {}, 
                "in": {
                  "$cond": {
                    "if": "$$contact.pcontact._id", 
                    "then": "$$contact.pcontact._id", 
                    "else": "$$contact.tcontact._id"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }, 
      "userNumber": 1, 
      "userID": 1
    }
  }, {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "pc", 
      "on": "userID", 
      "whenMatched": "replace", 
      "whenNotMatched": "insert"
    }
  }
])
```

It is not a fully optimized query but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add $unset to db query.

```
db.temporaryCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $unset: "_id"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      userID: ObjectId("61d1efea2c0fab00340f47c8"),
    },
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "permanentCollection",
      on: "userID",
      whenMatched: "merge",
      whenNotMatched: "insert",
    },
  },
]);
```